# Add class on current menu in jQuery via window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html here that has a class of `js-nav` and `data-id` which I want to use to determine the current sliding menu.

```
<a class="nav-link js-nav" data-id="about" href="/#about">About</a>
```

What I did on my code is first get the current url and filter it out until I will get the current `#about` url. Then on will compare it with `data-id` if they are the same by adding `#` character in front of it. And then if they are equal, I must add a class `active-menu` on the anchor tag `js-nav` then to give it a highlight but I also need to remove any existing `active-menu` class on all of the items. Here's my code so far.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var link = url.split('/')[3];
var item = $('a[data-id]');

if ('#' + item == link){
  $('a.js-nav').toggleClass('active-menu')
```

What I want to achieve here is that I need to highlight the current menu by adding `active-menu` class on the current sliding anchor item which I determine via URL. I also need to remove any existing `active-menu` class to any anchor whenever I am adding the class to make sure only one item will have the active class.

Right now this code doesn't work especially that part where I am adding `#` character in the item variable in order to compare it with the link.

How can I fix the code in order to attain the right output?
      }

Answer (score 4):

There is some erros with your code:

```
var item = $('a[data-id'); //Missing ] at the end
```

If you want to get the `data-id` value you'll need to use `$('.nav-link').data('id');`

Then remove all `.active-menu` class from all your elements:

```
$('.active-menu').removeClass('active-menu');
```

And finally add the class to your desired element:

```
$('#' + item).toggleClass('active-menu');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = window.location.href;
// var link = url.split('/')[3]; --> This won't always work because it will depend on the number of slashes you have, so I would replace it with 
var link = window.location.hash
$('a.js-nav.active-menu').removeClass('active-menu'); //will remove all actives
$('a.js-nav[data-id="' + link.replace('#', '') + '"]').addClass('active-menu'); //will add the class to the one you want
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function activateNavLink() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var link = url.split('/')[3];

  link = 'about'; // <<<< for demo only remove this line 

  $('.nav-link.js-nav').removeClass('active-menu'); // remove all active 
  $('a[data-id="' + link + '"]').addClass('active-menu'); // add active to only this
}


activateNavLink();
```

```css
.active-menu {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav-link js-nav" data-id="about" href="/#about">About</a> -
<a class="nav-link js-nav" data-id="contactus" href="/#contactus">Contact Us</a>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```